# Call function with named parameters from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, arguments

Let's say I have such function:

```
def fun(n, m, verbose=0, use_fib_heap=False):
    '''blah blah'''
    pass
```

Then I parse command line args and try to run it as specified:

```
from sys import argv
opts = dict()
for arg in argv[1:]:
    if arg.startswith('--'):
        if '=' in arg:
            p, v = arg[2:].split('=')[:2]
            opts[p] = v
        else:
            p = arg[2:]
            opts[p] = True
```

How can I call `fun`, if I run my code as `python3 code.py --verbose=3 --use_fib_heap`?

Comment: at the end of your script defining `opts` - `fun(**opts)`?

Answer (score 0):

just call the function normally

```
from sys import argv
opts = dict()
for arg in argv[1:]:
    if arg.startswith('--'):
        if '=' in arg:
            p, v = arg[2:].split('=')[:2]
            opts[p] = v
        else:
            p = arg[2:]
            opts[p] = True
        fun(with_params)
```

Comment: what is `with_params`?